# HBase inserts from arbitrary JSON with row-id

Tags: json, hadoop, hbase, data-warehouse, schemaless

**Is there any software which converts any given JSON to HBase (JSON or Thrift) insert?**

Let's say I receive following JSON to my stream

```
{  
   "_id":"www.somesite.com",
   "values":[  
      {  
         "label":"test_label"
      },
      {  
         "descr":"custom_descr"
      }
   ]
}
```

In order to add this information to `Hbase` i need to send `HTTP PUT` to `http://192.168.44.187:8000/<TABLE>/<ROW_ID>/<COL_FAMILY>:<COLUMN>`, whether i will need to change it to  `<ROW_ID> = www.somesite.com` and so on. Thus, `http://192.168.44.187:8000/t1/www.somesite.com/ColFam:label` to add `label`. Moreover body of `PUT` must contain corresponding `base64` formatted values.

```
{
   "Row":[
      {
         "key":"d3d3LnNvbWVzaXRlLmNvbTIy",
         "Cell":[
            {
               "column":"bGFiZWw=",
               "$":"dGVzdF9sYWJlbA=="
            }
         ]
     } 
   ]
}
```

Comment: you can write simple bash or python script to convert your JSON with base64 values and POST json data

Answer (score 0):

There is no such software. You can write a script/program in your favorite language to build the url and body for HTTP post request.